# Is it unprofessional to delay my start date due to sickness?

Tags: new-job, sickness

I am meant to start my new job on May 2nd, but I got a terrible back injury. I'm in a lot of pain and unable to move around a lot or think clearly. I might need 1 week extra to recover. The company were pretty flexible with the start date.

Comment: Get a doctor's note

Comment: Where in the world are you? In some places, delaying your start date would be stupid, given you can get a doctors note.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whether it is unprofessional is irrelevant. In your situation, you don't have a choice other than delaying your start date. If it takes a week for your back to recover, then that's how long it takes.

Mail the company requesting to delay your start date because of your back injury. Then call your manager or HR to discuss the situation. It may also be a good idea to add some buffer, so that if your recovery takes longer than a week, you don't have to delay the start date *again*. Requesting them to let you join sooner than agreed (if you recover early) would be definitely less embarrassing.

Comment: This is a start up position, they are very flexible about the start date and they are very understanding people. So I am thinking it might be ok.